# Translating a working regex for Twig match

Tags: regex, twig

I've got a regex working that I'm unable to use with Twig match. Basically, I need to confirm if a message contains `"@firstname lastname "` in it anywhere. The message can have returns, multiple matches, etc. The regex must match the entire message as long as `"@firstname lastname "` exists in it somewhere.

This is the regex I got working here: https://regexr.com/

```
/.+?(?=@)@[A-z]+ [A-z]+ (.*)/gs
```

And it worked for: This is a bunch of text surrounding @firstname lastname and so forth

What I tried:

```
{%- set action -%}
    Twig needs to handle the set in this format @firstname lastname
    for what I need to work
{%- endset -%}
```

And:

```
{% set regex = '/.+?(?=@)@[A-z]+ [A-z]+ (.*)/gs' %}
```

Then:

```
{% if action matches regex %}
    Working
{% else %}
    Not working
{% endif %}
```

What I get is: `Not Working`

Comment: Try `^[^@]*@\w+ \w+[\S\s]*$` https://regex101.com/r/erteNl/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no space between `lastname` and `for`, also `g` is not a valid [modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in `PHP`

```
{% set regex = '/.+?(?=@)@[A-z]+ [A-z]+(.*)/s' %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/cpiesr)